# Python: Split String into list of lists of lists

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string like `"2 2, 2 5, 3 1; 3 3, 4 4, 1 6; 1 1, 4 0;"`. `;` is dividing the string into 4 big chunks, the next level are the `,` the last would be whitespace.
My goal is to split the string into a list of lists of lists but I got stuck. Here is my code.

```
S = "2 2, 2 5, 3 1; 3 3, 4 4, 1 6; 1 1, 4 0;"
T = [elem.strip() for elem in S.split(";")]
U = []
V = []

for i in range(0,len(T)):
    U.append([elem.strip() for elem in T[i].split(',')])

for i in range(0,len(U)):
    for j in range(0,len(U[i])):
        V.append(U[i][j].split())

print("S = ", S)
print("U = ", U)
print("V = ", V)
```

With the output:

```
S =  2 2, 2 5, 3 1; 3 3, 4 4, 1 6; 1 1, 4 0;
T =  ['2 2, 2 5, 3 1', '3 3, 4 4, 1 6', '1 1, 4 0', '']
U =  [['2 2', '2 5', '3 1'], ['3 3', '4 4', '1 6'], ['1 1', '4 0'], ['']]
V =  [['2', '2'], ['2', '5'], ['3', '1'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '4'], 
     ['1', '6'], ['1', '1'], ['4', '0'], []]
```

V is not how I want it to be. I want `['2', '2'], ['2', '5'], ['3', '1']` to be contained in a separate list (the others as well).

What am I missing?

Bonus question: That string represents a graph where the places separated by `;` represent a node, places separated by `,` represent their neighbor represented by that neighbors node-number and distance (which are separated by whitespace)
Is there a better way to store this graph in a primitive datatype without building a class?

Comment: For your bonus question take a look at this Wikipedia article which lists common implementations and their efficiency in both memory and speed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29#Representations

This is an adjacent list stored in a dictionary:
https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested comprehension to split further and further:

```
V = [[map(int, j.split()) for j in i.split(',')] for i in s.split(';')]
```

Comment: You can use the same principles to create the others.

Comment: Whoa. Great! I'm really new to Python so these solutions amaze me.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can convert all these single strings into int in that list comprehension? So the final nested list is the same just with ints instead of strings.

Comment: Let me make a quick edit and if you could please mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

For question 1, you should write like this:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

S = "2 2, 2 5, 3 1; 3 3, 4 4, 1 6; 1 1, 4 0;"
T = [elem.strip() for elem in S.split(";")]
U = []
V = []
for i in range(0,len(T)):
    U.append([elem.strip() for elem in T[i].split(',')])

for i in U:
    temp = []
    for m in i:
        temp.append(m.split())
    V.append(temp)

print("S = ", S)
print("U = ", U)
print("V = ", V)
```

OUTPUT:

```
('S = ', '2 2, 2 5, 3 1; 3 3, 4 4, 1 6; 1 1, 4 0;')
('U = ', [['2 2', '2 5', '3 1'], ['3 3', '4 4', '1 6'], ['1 1', '4 0'], ['']])
('V = ', [[['2', '2'], ['2', '5'], ['3', '1']], [['3', '3'], ['4', '4'], ['1', '6']], [['1', '1'], ['4', '0']], [[]]])
```

For question 2, you can map this string to a 'nested' dictionary if you want to show logic between all these content.

Comment: Q2: I thought about that. But since I'm just using that graph description to get the shortest path, I don't think a dictionary would make it easier to iterate over the graph properties.